# ui for increasing and decreasing a value ... like datepicker in android

Tags: android, user-interface, datepicker

I want to make something like this in android

[image: value picker]

this is a part of the datepicker, so How can i extract it to use only the value picker.

If it is not applicable to do this, tell me about any alternatives.

Comment: try to modify this wheel view, http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/downloads/detail?name=wheel-demo-2.1.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: https://github.com/mrn/numberpicker

Comment: please don't copy the iOS wheel. it's terrible.

Comment: Better talk to the Android people then... that's the Android NumberPicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer the links

http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5

http://www.technologichron.net/?p=42

similar questions  asked here

[Android Number Picker Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359510/android-number-picker-dialog)

[Android dialog number picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633343/android-dialog-number-picker)

Answer (score 1):

The standard android NumberPicker widgets looks exactly like that.  Unfortunately, it's only available in Android 3.0 and up, so if you are targeting earlier versions, you will need to use a library.

Documentation for the android version can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html).

Since others have already pointed you to possible libraries, I won't repeat that here.  I'll show you how to use the standard NumberPicker for Android 3.0+.

In your xml layout (setting width to 100 dip allows for a three digit number, adjust according to your needs):

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberpicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:width="100dip" />
```

In your code:

```
NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberpicker);  // get the widget
np.setMaxValue(10);                                                 // set the max value
np.setMinValue(0);                                                 // set the min value
np.setValue(5);                                                    // set initail display value
np.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);                                     // start over when reaching top or bottom
```

And a screenshot of it:

[image]