# How to create custom Numeric Up Down control like ajax in android?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-controls

I cannot find any control in android as like Numeric Up Down in ajax. Please suggest me any usable link or provide some code for creating Numeric Up Down control in android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android having NumericUpDown Button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307213/android-having-numericupdown-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing for this publicly in the Android SDK. You have the `NumerPicker` in `com.android.internal.widget.NumberPicker` but as the name suggest, it's internal so not intended for public use.

Luckily, a few people have made their own version of this `NumberPicker`. Here are some custom views you can use:

- [Android Number Picker (my favorite)](http://www.technologichron.net/?p=42)
- [NumberPicker Widget](http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5)