# Android Number Picker Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, numbers

Does anyone have any dialogs that will allow a user to pick a number within a certain range? It seems like this would be a fairly common need, but I can't find a common dialog for it and I'd rather not have to spend the time creating my own.

Any help?

Answer (score 33):

I know that more than two years passed but answer is still actual and I find some nice Number Pickers. Here is one of them
https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker

[image]

Comment: This is a fantastic implementation of a number picker. Very slick! Thanks so much for sharing.

Comment: thanks to guy who made it:)

Comment: it does not show top/ bottom arrow. Did I missed anything?

Comment: @ashish arrow are disappeared when scrolling

Comment: The arrow never been shown...not even in the sample.

Comment: @ashish Sorry, I didn't have such problems

Comment: I don't get arrows shown on mine!

Comment: it can hide previous one and next one number?

Answer (score 11):

It's available in SDK since API 11 - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

Comment: ... and unfortunately not in the compatibility lib.

Answer (score 3):

I've just released some code that does just what you want. Check out my custom control, NumberPicker, which can be seen here: http://www.technologichron.net/?p=42

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but for any that are interested, http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/ is a good implementation.

Comment: It seems a little iOS style...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe useful:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/65da9820998fddc9