# Develop Bi-directional Spinner in Android

Tags: android

I need to create a Bi-directional spinner in Android .
Providing the following sample:

[image]

Can anyone provide any inputs ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

[Android Number Picker Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359510/android-number-picker-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with @Matt that a number picker is probably the best way.  I wouldn't try and exactly duplicate the look of a windows form, as on a touch screen those up/down arrows are going to be very small.

If you really want the up/down functionality and are planning on using much larger buttons then you just need a couple of `onClickListener`s, one to increment the value and one to decrement.