# How to add number range in android preferences

Tags: android

I've been trying to add a number spinner in android just like in the android docs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

[image: http://developer.android.com/images/ui/settings/settings.png]

But after much research I wasn't able to figure this out: some are suggesting using the Cyanogenmod one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515062/create-numberpicker-dialog-in-preference) or [QuetlyCoding library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756223/android-how-to-use-numberpickerdialog) I'm wondering if these are the only options? Is there something built in like the "Text Message limit" in the picture?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android PreferenceActivity dialog with number picker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758986/android-preferenceactivity-dialog-with-number-picker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) class which allows selecting a number from the predefined range. You can create a custom dialog, which uses this control.

Comment: Thanks, there are multiple pages with info on how to do this, e.g. https://gist.github.com/thom-nic/959884