# How to use NumberPicker widget Android 4.0

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to configure the `NumberPicker` widget using **API 14**. There are very little tutorials or instructions online that would help me set it up properly.

so far I have the following code implemented in *main.xml*:

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

and in the main activity in the onCreate() method:

```
NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
    String[] nums = new String[20];
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
           nums[i] = Integer.toString(i);

    np.setMinValue(1);
    np.setMaxValue(20);
    np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    np.setDisplayedValues(nums);
    np.setValue(1);
```

When running my application in the emulator the numberpicker widget does not get displayed as expected. The button's are not left and right but up and down. And the values overlay each other instead of one number being displayed. Clicking an arrow crashes the application.

**EDIT**

Made changes as described below in first answer however the numberpciker is not usable, please see screenshot:

[image: Numberpicker screenshot]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it looks like the `MatchPicker` inherits the `android:orientation` XML attribute from a parent class, so that might be the issue. try getting rid of that line too and see if it works. i'm trying to find a way to display the values horizontally online...

Comment: Is there any way to get the background wheel image too on Android 4.0.x? It works like a charm on later versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try commenting out the for loop and the line `np.setDisplayedValues(nums);`. The `NumberPicker` should display the values for you automatically.

You might also consider changing the width to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` if you want the `NumberPicker` to display your values horizontally.

---

### EDIT:

It appears that you cannot change `NumberPicker` (see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6797248/844882)). The issue is that you are trying to change the `android:orientation` attribute... but this is an inherited attribute from the `LinearLayout` class. You might be stuck with a vertically displaying `NumberPicker` unless you customize your own. Sorry!

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I have made the changes you advised me to do however the numberpicker is still not usable.

Answer (score 2):

Change the height of the NumberPicker to 200dp. It's simply because it can't display the picker in the height you specified (48dp), because of this it messes up the rendering calculations.