# How to get the selected number from NumberPicker?

Tags: java, android, numberpicker

I have two number pickers, I want to get the value that user chose from thos number pickers. then convert them to String.

Any idea?

Comment: Some documentation on NumberPicker for Android. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html Also, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279785/how-to-use-numberpicker-widget-android-4-0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get current picked number by calling getValue(), eg. if you have myPicker, you can do this:

```
String value = "" + myPicker.getValue();
```

If you want to get the value when it's selected by user, you need to implement NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener interface:

```
private class MyListener implements NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        //get new value and convert it to String
        //if you want to use variable value elsewhere, declare it as a field 
        //of your main function
        String value = "" + newVal;
    }
}
```

Remember to set your listener, eg:

```
myPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new MyListener());
```