# How to take NumberPicker values set by user?

Tags: android, numberpicker

So I am working on my first app and I have some problems trying to take the values set by the user on two number pickers in one screen.

Here is the code for that screen.

```
    NumberPicker np =(NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.piker);
    final String[] vrednosti= {"никогаш","ретко","секој ден"};
    np.setMinValue(0);
    np.setMaxValue(vrednosti.length-1);
    np.setDisplayedValues(vrednosti);
    np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    np.setValue(1);

    NumberPicker np2 =(NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.piker2);
    np2.setMinValue(40);
    np2.setMaxValue(150);
    np2.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    np2.setValue(60);
```

I want to take the values so that I can use them in my calculator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the selected number from NumberPicker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181836/how-to-get-the-selected-number-from-numberpicker)

Comment: Have you tried `np.getValue()`?

Comment: The getValue doesn't give back the selected value from the user. It gets only the default value

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal I checked that question but it didnt help me out.

Comment: Try to call `np.clearFocus();` before calling `np.getValue();`

Comment: @VasilyKabunov I tried that, but the app crashes. I just changed the NumberPicker with basic Number insertion.