# NumberPicker in Horizontal mode

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a `NumberPicker`. But by default it is in vertical mode. Can I set to horizontal mode?

This is my NumberPicker:

```
<NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberpickercontrol"
        style="@style/AndroDev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: oops sorry.. bydefault it is in Vertical mode......

Comment: possible duplicate of [It is possible to make a horizontal NumberPicker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796243/it-is-possible-to-make-a-horizontal-numberpicker)

Comment: use this `android:orientation="horizontal"`

Comment: Hi Vijay, that was a nice question. I have an issue with the orientation. Even after setting to `horizontal` and the `LinearLayout` as well to `horizontal`, it still is vertical. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

After not finding a solution i decided to make my own implementation. Its the version with selector wheel, not with buttons and styled for xhdpi . This are the files:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1iiecalum0ahwa/numberpickerhorizontal.rar?dl=0

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -5):

Did you try to change `android:orientation` ?

Just change the value for what you want (horizontal or vertical).

Comment: it will not rotate the picker