# Create a number picker in horizontal mode, did android:orientation="horizontal" work? I have try but the number picker still same in vertical mode

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-number-picker

I want to create a number picker in horizontal mode, but i set the  android:orientation="horizontal", it still cannot work. How can i create the number picker in horizontal mode just like the pic below ?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.example.sam.weighttrack.KeyInWeightF">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/payment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

`NumberPicker` does not support horizontal orientation. So you have to write your own or use one of few existed libraries:

1. [HorizontalPicker](https://github.com/blazsolar/HorizontalPicker)
2. [android-spinnerwheel](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel)

Comment: Im using android studio 
im asking for number picker in horizontal mode, but the HorizontalPicker is  a tab lolz. Can u give an example of code so i can get understanding easily

Comment: I also had to make my own, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37704644/2102748