# TimePicker-like widget

Tags: android, datepicker, timepicker

is it any possibility to get a spin box like the ones used in Time or DatePickers? I want to set my own data using those.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More precisely, I think you are looking for this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html.

EDIT:

Or if you're looking into other options, it already has been discussed here: [Android Number Picker Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359510/android-number-picker-dialog).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

it is possible via a custom view... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

happy coding ;)