# Why is NumberPicker (up-down-domain picker) not visibility in Android UI Editor at Eclipse?

Tags: android

up-down-domain picker is a popular/general UI component, but anytime I have to add it by hand.Why is NumberPicker (up-down-domain picker) not visibility in Android UI Editor at Eclipse?

```
<android.widget.NumberPicker
android:id="@+id/ppp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

---

I got it! NumberPicker widget supports Android SDK since API level 11 = Android 3.0+ OS, and my project is based on Android 2.x OS.

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359510/android-number-picker-dialog Can you please post relevant code to check that where the issue will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NumberPicker` was introduced in API 11. If you are not building your application against Android 3.0+, Eclipse will not be able to display the `View` in the UI editor.