# How to have this type of time picker in Android?

Tags: android, layout, timepicker

I am developing an application in which i want to show time picker to set a time for reminder. Right now I am able to show a time-picker using preference screen like this

```
<org.example.android.TimePreference
 android:defaultValue="12:00"
 android:key="check_time"
 android:summary="Set your desired time for check"
 android:title="Check time" />
```

`TimePreference.java` file is inherited from this [TimePicker in PreferenceScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533078/timepicker-in-preferencescreen) link. But I want to show this on button click in particular activity and set it values in `EditText` or in `TextView`. I don't want to use preferences.

So, I want to make the layout of this screen like below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this tutorial . you will get the project over there .
http://www.zainodis.com/2011/05/android-custom-timepicker.html

have a look at this example number picker.. like this you can change it into for time picker.
[Android Number Picker Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359510/android-number-picker-dialog)

Comment: File doesn't exists in your first link, can you provide me that source if you have ?

Comment: do you have source code of your first link which you mentioned in your answer,it would be great if you can provide me :)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is depending on the API level you are working with.

API level < 11: You'll have to backport the [`NumberPicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) by copying it's [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java) in your project and modifying it to your needs

API level >= 11: You can use the standard implementation of the [`NumberPicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) and extend it to your needs.