# Extract Minutes Control from time picker in android

Tags: android, controls, timepicker, minute

Hi can any tell me how to get a control similar to the minutes control in time picker control. Is there any other way of achieving it. All that i need is just the minutes selector.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post may help explaining how to use a NumberPicker Widget: [Is there a view for inputing integers in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523510/is-there-a-view-for-inputing-integers-in-android)

Comment: Hi Maximus i m getting this exception how can i rectify it 'Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.internal.widget.NumberPicker in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader'

Comment: Read through that post... I've not used it but I guess the issue is that you can't get at that class any longer, though there are links you can follow to get to the source.

Comment: Thanks Maximus i found this [link](http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5) to be very useful