# How to make android edittext for numeric similar to the up/down buttons on DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-edittext, int

I want to make an integer edittext field where the user can use plus/minus buttons to increment and decrement the integer value in the edittext field.  I would like it to be just like the DatePickerDialog where you can change the day, month, year using little up and down buttons.  Is there a standard Android widget that I can use to achieve this interface -- or is it necessary to piece it together myself using two buttons and an edittext field?

Update: this is a minSDKVersion API 7 app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use this..

This seems to be exactly what you are looking for

[Number picker demo](https://github.com/novak/numpicker-demo)

Comment: This looks like a complete time and date picker interface?  What I want is just a single integer entry after the fashion of the datepicker -- how do I do that?

Comment: So you want to just pick a number instead of a date or time?

Comment: This looks like a complete and proper solution, I'm inclined to select this as best answer -- I just want to try it out first.  Thanks!

Comment: @coder_For_Life22, please send the updated link.. It is showing page not found error:(

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you're looking for? [number picker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html)

Comment: Just one note: NumberPicker is only available since API 11 (that's HoneyComb)

Comment: This does look like exactly what I wanted.  Yikes, I'm not doing Honeycomb!  Is there a solution back to API 7 or 8?

Comment: Oh yes, That's API 11. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523510/is-there-a-view-for-inputing-integers-in-android)

Comment: That looks very promising, thanks!  I'll give it a try and get back.